# Cross-browser drag-and-drop HTTP file upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I'm looking for a cross-browser html file uploader with drag-and-drop capability. Ideally the drop target area can be large and overlap other elements (ie. I'd like to allow the user to drop the item on existing parts of the HTML UI instead of requiring a separate target area).

Cross browser support (including IE6) is important, as is reliability. I'm using jQuery, but am open to good solutions that don't use jQuery.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Give FileDrop a try:

http://proger.i-forge.net/FileDrop_-_cross-browser_JavaScript_Drag-Drop_file_upload/7CC

As per the site:

> supports Firefox 3.6, Internet Explorer 6, Google Chrome 7, Apple Safari 5 and Opera 11.61 (Opera 12+ supports native drag & drop).

Keep in mind drag-and-drop doesn't work in IE < 10 though.

Not sure if the drop area will work as you want, you will have to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

Plupload maby, though i have not managed to find a browser compatibility list...

http://www.plupload.com/

https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload